# c++0x lambdas, not letting me pass as function ptr

Tags: boost, lambda, bind, boost-asio, c++11

I am currently writing a program in C++0x which I am fairly new to.
I am setting up callbacks between objects and using lambda to match the types (like `boost::bind()` does in ways)

If I call a function in the asio library like:

```
 socket_.async_read_some(buffer(&(pBuf->front()), szBuffer),                                                    
     [=](const boost::system::error_code &error, size_t byTrans) {                                               
                      this->doneRead(callBack, pBuf, error, byTrans); });
```

This compiles fine, and runs as expected, 'doneRead' is called back from 'async_read_some'

so I have a similar call back in my own code:

```
client->asyncRead([=](string msg){this->newMsg(msg); });
```

This takes just a string, and asyncReads prototype is as follows

```
void ClientConnection::asyncRead(void(*callBack)(string))
```

But I get this compile error:

> Server.cpp: In member function ‘void
>   Server::clientAccepted(std::shared_ptr,
>   const boost::system::error_code&)’:
>   Server.cpp:31:3: error: no matching
>   function for call to
>   ‘ClientConnection::asyncRead(Server::clientAccepted(std::shared_ptr,
>   const
>   boost::system::error_code&)::)’
>   Server.cpp:31:3: note: candidate is:
>   ClientConnection.h:16:9: note: void
>   ClientConnection::asyncRead(void
>   (*)(std::string))
>   ClientConnection.h:16:9: note:   no
>   known conversion for argument 1 from
>   ‘Server::clientAccepted(std::shared_ptr,
>   const
>   boost::system::error_code&)::’
>   to ‘void (*)(std::string)’

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: Can you share Server::clientAccepted. It looks like you are using the provided callback there and there is a mismatch between the type of lambda that the clientAccepted function accepts to what you are passing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your lambda captures `this` implicitly. A lambda that captures things cannot convert to a raw function pointer.

So you need to write `asyncRead` so it accepts the lambda function object directly, instead of letting it convert to a function pointer

```
template<typename CallbackType>
void ClientConnection::asyncRead(CallbackType callback);
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to write this as a template, you can use a polymorphic function object wrapper

```
void ClientConnection::asyncRead(std::function<void(string)> callBack);
```

I would also consider changing the callback's interface so it accepts the string by const reference (unless all the callback implementations inherently want to modify or save/move the passed string internally, which seem unlikely in your case).

Comment: so i don't suppose you know whether you second way is the way that boost does it? I am trying that  way now.

Comment: yes this (the second) seems to have sussed it, thanks a ton brother.